# Django - List Filtering using a ForeignKey within a ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I can filter the list of Bookings from "housing" using the "Housing" ForeignKey

But I need to do it based on the h_type which uses the "HousingType" ForeignKey

I am not sure of the correct terminology here but I think I am trying to use a ForeignKey within a ForeignKey, not sure how to accomplish this within the view.

**models.py**

```
class HousingType(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    friendly_name = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=True, blank=True)

class Housing(models.Model):

    h_type = models.ForeignKey('HousingType', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

class Booking(models.Model):

    housing = models.ForeignKey('Housing', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

**views.py**

```
def view_bookings(request):

    housing = Housing.objects.all()
    bookings = Booking.objects.all()

    if request.GET:
        if 'housing_type' in request.GET:
            h_types = request.GET['housing_type'].split(',')
            bookings = bookings.filter(housing_type__name__in=h_types)
            h_types = HousingType.objects.filter(name__in=h_types)
```

**html template**

```
<a href="{% url 'view_bookings' %}?housing_type=apartments">Apartments</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [**`.filter(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#filter) with:

```
Booking.objects.filter(housing__h_type__name__in=h_types)
```

or if you use the `friendly_name`:

```
Booking.objects.filter(housing__h_type__friendly_name__in=h_types)
```